# How can i click on like button instagram?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I would like to know how I can programmatically click on the "like" button of a publication in Instagram.

This is not for an auto like or stuff like, I am developing an Android application, and would like to display company publications (owner of the app), and allow users to "like" Instagram publications. I plan to add one like button underneath a photo, (the photo that was published in Instagram) so I allow the user to enter the Instagram through a WebView, and in this WebView that the user is logged in, when I can trigger a javascript function for that click on the like button of the publication.

I hope you have understood my need.

Comment: Did you look at their api?

Comment: I have seen the instagram api, but are no longer accepting applications.